# Advanced algebra circa 1969

Tags: algebra

For almost 50 years, I've been looking for a textbook I had as a 12th grader in Abe Lincoln HS (Brooklyn) in 1969; a book that opened my eyes up to math- which resulted in me going into actuarial work.

All I remember is that it was a big, heavy book, yellowish-greenish cover, with quadratic equations on the cover- - (b^2-4ac). If I had it in 1969 it must have been printed in the few years before then.

Please, if anyone remembers the title or likely author please e-mail Gary Rothy at actuarylaw@yahoo.com

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the practice of mathematics education. I suggest posting elsewhere, perhaps on reddit, Twitter, or some other forum.

Comment: Try contacting the school to see if they have records of previously used textbooks.  It's unlikely they'd go back that far, but worth a shot.